# Delegate method drawLayer: inContext not called

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, calayer, quartz-2d

I'm struggling to find the missing piece in my code.I have a class which derives from UIView(customView) and also have a class that derives from CALayer (customLayer) and implements the drawLayer:inContext delegate method of the CALayer class.I do that because I want to use the customLayer as a clipping mask and so I need the drawLayer: inContext method which is not called when I start the application.
Here is a snippet of my code

```
@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; 
        // Initialization code
        CustomLayer *customLayer= [CALayer layer];     
        customLayer.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.6 blue:0.2  alpha:0.4].CGColor;
        customLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        customLayer.delegate=customLayer;
        [customLayer setNeedsDisplay];
        [self.layer addSublayer:customLayer];
     }
  return self;
}
```

and the customLayer implementation:

```
@implementation CustomLayer

-(void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    NSLog(@"drawLayer:inContext");
    CGContextBeginPath (ctx);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, self.frame);
    CGContextClosePath (ctx);
    CGContextClip (ctx);
}
```

I really can't figure out what is going on.Any advices will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updating based on conversation in comments*

First, this line:

```
CustomLayer *customLayer= [CALayer layer];
```

needs to use your CustomLayer:

```
CustomLayer *customLayer= [CustomLayer layer];
```

That said, setting the customLayer as its own delegate is a bit odd, you may actually be running into code preventing this.

Have you tried using the `- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` method?  Generally, each CALayerDelegate method has a corresponding CALayer method that you can override in subclasses.

```
-(void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    NSLog(@"drawLayer:inContext");
    CGContextBeginPath (ctx);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, self.frame);
    CGContextClosePath (ctx);
    CGContextClip (ctx);

    // Note: this is where your original code ended, you have successfully set up a clipping path, but you haven't drawn anything to actually get clipped!
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.4);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
}
```

Also, are you setting the frame (bounds/position//center) of the CustomLayer instance?  I see you adding it to the layer hierarchy, but at the default 0,0 size.

Comment: Yes,I tried this and it's still not working.YEs, I set the frame its a typo in my post.

Comment: I only realized a few minutes ago that you aren't actually drawing anything in the -draw... method, you are just setting up a clipping path.  I updated my answer above, if you do that, do you get an ellipse?  Note: I suspect that ultimately you want to be using CALayer.mask here, not CoreGraphics clipping paths.

Comment: I saw your note but this doesn't solve the problem.The method just doesn't get called no matter what I try.

Comment: My idea is taken from here:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html

Check Figure 3-3. and Listing 3-1

*Yes background color shows,the layer is added but not clipped.

Comment: `CustomLayer *customLayer= [CALayer layer];` needs to be `CustomLayer *customLayer= [CustomLayer layer];` , or else your subclass won't get instantiated.  I'd move this to a chat so we could discuss, but I sadly can't do that yet.  Once I change that line, my -drawInContext: method is getting called.

Comment: YES you are totally right! Thank you very much for this answer!Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to vote up.

Comment: That's fine ;)  I'm not worried about rep - but I am still a bit concerned that this is the wrong approach.  Ultimately, are you trying to just get a canvas to draw into?  Or do you want to create a clipping region that updates dynamically?